# Is it possible to host multiple clients/organizations on a Superset server?

Tags: security, apache-superset

Can use the same Superset server for different clients of ours? Could we setup organizations in Superset so that the client is only able to access/view only the organization they belong to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390754/create-database-kind-of-thing-in-druid