# Create database kind of thing in Druid

Tags: apache-superset, druid

I am using druid to store data for creating dashboard over superset. Now, I want to use the same cluster to store data for other project which is not completely different. But we want to segregate datasources of both the projects.

Is there a way to create database/keyspace sort of thing to segregate datasources of two different project in druid?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple way to work with this use case.

Easiest one create multiple datasources into superset. Based on the same connection to druid.

Then create roles to provide access to this datasources. Then end user will have 1 or multiple roles. Each role providing data from druid but from different perspective. Every user will be able to create his own dash based on this dataset if allowed by role.

Other way is to user row security level. Each row has a specific tag. Each user is configured to have access to 1 or many tags. This approch allow you to have the same dash for all users

More ressources here => https://superset.apache.org/docs/security